# Accesing to /usr/local/lib through Xcode 4

Tags: opencv, xcode4.5, dylib

I am trying to use OpenCV within Xcode. I was following [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1145869) but OpenCV's dylib are in `/usr/local/lib` and not in `/opt/local/lib` is there a way to see the first path within Xcode? Should I change the install path of OpenCV? I don't know if there's a difference between `/usr/local` and `/opt/local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link assumes that `/opt/local/` is the install path of the OpenCV libraries. You should be able to simply replace `/opt/local/` in the tutorial with `/usr/local/`.

And yes, the two paths are different locations.

Comment: Yes I know those are different locations (but what's the difference? is it better to install my stuff in opt?) the problem is when I click the `Add other` there's no way to access to `/usr/local/<whatever>` apparently that path is hidden from within Xcode, but how to make it available/accesible?

Comment: In the `Add other` dialog you can press `command+shift+G` and then type the path. You should be able to navigate to the correct files after that. As far as `/opt` versus `/usr/local/`, it seems to be a matter of [preference](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/pointcounterpoint-opt-vs-usrlocal?page=0,0).